# SharePoint 2010 permission issues

Tags: 2010, permissions

I have a SP 2010 site and I am facing some permission issues. First of all the site collection administrators can see the Delete Page button available on some but not all site pages? In some pages they are greyed out. Some of the site pages have their own permissions but I believe Site collection Administrators should not be affected by those permissions or am I wrong?

Secondly, there is a domain group in the site with Read-Only permission on the root level and Read-only permission on some libraries and site pages but users in this group can actually see the Delete page option on the ribbon!!

Can someone shed some light on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delete page button will be disabled for anybody (even site collection admins) if the page is not in edit mode (and also checked out, if checkout is required on the library containing the pages). It will also be disabled on the default homepage of a site.

As for the domain group's access, you should check the page permissions on the specific pages where they are able to see the delete button. Use the "Check Permissions" button on the page's Permission Settings to enter a specific user and see how they have access. Note that permissions in SharePoint are cumulatively permissive; if I have "Read Only" access on a document from being a member of one group, and "Contribute" access on the document from being a member of a different group, I'll effectively have the more permissive "Contribute" permissions on the document.

Comment: the page is not in edit mode and still on i can see the delete page option.
For the domain groups access the permission on the page is Limited access/Read only.
There are only two groups on that site page have only Read Only permission. On one group the Read Only applies but not on the other.